# Video format/codec for PowerPoint 2007?

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, codec, video-conversion, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I would like to add video files to PowerPoint 2007 slides (on PC).

1) Which codec should I use for maximum quality?
1b) Does this depend on computer-specific installed plugins/codecs?

2) Is there any format that would allow me to develop the presentation on Mac and then move it to a PC without having to convert the video files?

Thank you!